# Chrome onMessage not returing value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, runtime

Please help me understand this.
Extension was running great. No errors or anything. Literally left to eat came back and ran it. nothing working. Getting two errors:

1. Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'a' of undefined: `popup.js:21 (setAction)`
2. Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Trying to troubleshoot I simplified my code so I could try to understand what is going wrong.

Here is my code.

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('beginSign').addEventListener('click', onBeginClick, false)
    var actionText = document.getElementById('actionText')

    function onBeginClick() {
        chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},
            function (tabs){
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "0"}, setAction)
            })
    }


    function setAction(res){
        if(res.a == 0){
            actionText.textContent = "Currently Signing!"
        }
    }
})
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        sendResponse({a: 0})
    }
)
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for error 1: then `sendResponse` call back function does not always return reliable value. so do not use it. use another way:
in your `popup.js`:

```
 function onBeginClick() {
        chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},
            function (tabs){
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "0"}, null)
            })
    }
// set another event listener
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(request => setAction)

function setAction(res){
        if(res.a == 0){
            actionText.textContent = "Currently Signing!"
        }
    }
```

in your `content.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({a: 0})
    }
)
```

for your error 2: 
if you reloaded your extension in chrome's extension management page, you have to reload a page you opened to reload the content script too.

Comment: "sendResponse call back function does not always return reliable value" - this is phrased really wrong because it's just isn't true and switching to a separate sendMessage won't help. The actual underlying problem here is that the content script isn't running at all when the message was sent as you explained at the end of the answer.

Comment: If content script isn't wrong, will be error 2. Not 1.